# How to animate text(), html() jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, text, jquery-animate

Hello I made script that change words but I want to add animation when text is changing. How I can do it?

[Link here](http://jsbin.com/umUWAGu/1/edit)

Comment: Doesn't it already have animation? What exactly do you want it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start a animation, and direct after starting it you stop it:

```
$(".dynamo").animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500).stop();
```

Use

```
$(".dynamo")
    .stop() // Stop on-going animation
    .animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500, function() {
        // After first animation finished
        $(this).html(array[i]).animate({ opacity: 1 });
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/umUWAGu/2

Comment: this function in animate is callback function? I'm begginer.

Comment: That's indeed a callback function

Comment: so when the animation end and opacity is 0 function started?

Comment: Yes, according to the api (http://api.jquery.com/animate/): `complete -- Type: Function() -- A function to call once the animation is complete.`

Comment: thanks man :) have you any ideas where or how I can improve my jquery?

Comment: Avoid variable-names like `array` , it's confusing with the type-name `Array`. Confusions can lead to coding-errors. Give it a meaningful name like `dynamoContents`. The rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: okey :) have you any exercieses that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use fadeIn and fadeOut methods of jquery library.
You should create second element with position: absolute, set opacity to zero and animate both elements (of course, with removal of the first).